# "Unable to find a match Error" while trying to build a Docker image with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos7

I am trying to build a docker image containing Nginx Web Server and PHP.

I am using a VM with centos 7

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM remote-host

COPY ./conf/nginx.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum -y install nginx openssl --enablerepo=nginx && \
    yum -y update &&  \
    yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm --nobest --skip-broken && \
    yum -y install php71u-fpm php71u-cli && \
    yum clean all

EXPOSE 80 443

VOLUME /var/www/html /var/log/nginx /var/log/php-fpm /var/lib/php-fpm

COPY ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY ./bin/start.sh /start.sh

RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD /start.sh
```

This is the error output :

```
Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides epel-release = 7 needed by ius-release-2-1.el7.ius.noarch
================================================================================
Skip  1 Package

Nothing to do.
Complete!
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:22 ago on Fri Dec  6 23:07:40 2019.
**No match for argument: php71u-fpm
No match for argument: php71u-cli
Error: Unable to find a match**
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y update &&     yum install -y epel-release &&     yum -y install nginx openssl --enablerepo=nginx &&     yum -y update &&      yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm --nobest --skip-broken &&     yum -y install php71u-fpm php71u-cli &&     yum clean all' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: May you try this yum --enablerepo=extras install -y epel-release

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately

Comment: I have the same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `epel-release` package is missing.

Make sure `CentOS` Extras repository includes a package to install EPEL

You can check with below comands

```
yum search epel-release
yum info epel-release
```

Comment: Yeah I had that issue at the beginning..but then I added  yum install -y epel-release && \ 6 line of my Dockerfile - still same issue. Note when I run  yum -y install php71u-fpm php71u-cli on my host machine it works, but not while building docker image

Answer (score 0):

the package family `php71u` [is deprecated](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-archive-x86_64/php71u-fpm-7.1.10-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html) but can be downloaded by setting the repo to be "ius-archive" instead of "ius-release". like wise:

```
yum --enablerepo=ius-archive install php71u-fpm
```